# Error establishing a database connection Centos 7

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb, centos7

I'm having a really hard time figuring a VPS server... My website shows up on occasion:

> Error establishing a database connection

This happens about once a day.

As soon as I reboot the server, the problem's gone. I've tried adding the following 2 lines in my `wp-config` file, as suggested on some other forums, but it didn't work:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); 
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

From what I read around the web, it seems that 512M of RAM is perfectly fine for a Wordpress site, if set correctly - 
though I'm having a hard time with a single (low content) site, without many plugins. I've also disabled/deleted the plugins that could potentially eat up a lot of memory, such as wp-backup and I use more than 1500M of Memory + 2 CPU in my server I use CentOS 7 64 bits.

If you have any suggestions for me, I'd be more than thankful! Please notice that I'm pretty new with all this, and as it's my first time running VPS on Centos, I do have a bit hard time understanding how everything works, at the moment...

Many in advance thanks to your response.

Comment: How busy is you SQL server? Have you checked the performance with for instance `top` to see how much processor it takes on such occasions? Maybe it has too many connections to serve all the queries?

Comment: How much RAM in the VPS?  What web server?  How many connections does the webserver allow?  What is the value of `max_connections`?

Comment: Thanks for your response The RAM is 2GB, the server is apache ,

I haven't any idea about connections does the web server allow and What is the value of max_connections i inform that the hoster is Gandi.

Thnks